# Export data to multiple related table in SQL Server from Excel

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a requirement for importing data from Excel to a database table. The Excel file has the following data.

[image]

Block can be NULL. All other field must have data.

I have four tables:

1. dbo.Building [BuildingID, Building]
2. dbo.Block [BlockID, Block, BuildingID]
3. dbo.Apartment [ApartmentID, Apartment, BuildingID, BlockID]
4. dbo.RoomNo [RoomNoID, RoomNo, ApartmentID]

each table has id as primary key which is identity.
Block contain Building ID as foreign key 
Apartment contain Building ID and Block ID as foreign key 
Room No contain Apartment ID as foreign key

I need to import the data from Excel to these related table with correct relation.

I successfully imported the data from Excel to a single table.

How can I insert Excel data to these related tables?

I need to do it with asp.net. user has a page to upload Excel file. After uploading the data should be copied to corresponding tables.

My logic goes like this,

- first I import this data to a temporary table, then I need to write an SP where, first I select the building and insert all distinct buildings to dbo.Building,
- Then I compare the buildings having block from temp table with dbo.Building and get BuildingID and insert the block details.
- Then I get apartments from the temporary table having matching buildingID and blockID from dbo.Building and dbo.Block and insert.
- Then I select apartment having no Block and get matching BuildingID and insert to dbo.apartment.
- **(I am confused here)** Then I select ApartmentID and Apartment from dbo.Apartment having Building = dbo.building and (Block = dbo.Block or dbo.Block IS NULL) and join with Temp table getting RoomNo comparing with Apartment, block, building and insert to dbo.RoomNo.

Will it work?

Comment: try with import and export wizard in sql server

Comment: I need to integrate this facility to asp.net website. No provision for getting Server management studio